# High Performance File I/O java API for file size of 300MB (max)

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, io, nio

Building an Application, which is meant for only File I/O (could be pdf,jpg etc). Maximum file size can be 300MB. Application will be deployed on Linux 64 bit.
Tried the traditional blocking IO(FileOutputStream etc). But I am looking for Non-blocking or some better approach with good performance.

Here is the code that I am using right now.

```
FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("path/filename");
imageOutFile.write(byteArray);
imageOutFile.close();
```

Please help me with better approach,code snippet for meeting this scenario. 
Rest service will have input as filemetada and bytestream as input to my Service.

Comment: Could you at least make some research on the subject by yourself and/or explaining *what kind* of result do you expect ? Depending on the field, your "high performance" criteria may be 2ms or 400ms. No one will answer you correctly in that state, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the destination for the data contained in the file? RAM? A ZIP file? A Jar file? A GZIP file? A different archive file? A different/new file? A socket? Some other output destination?

Comment: First, file R/W performance strongly depends on your storage device. And 300 MB isn't that big but it is big!

Comment: @swaroop have a look at `AsynchronousFileChannel` and how to use them with `CompletableFuture` that should set you up for a long run, also try to ask a more specific question on this platform. Like how to use Asynch channel with Completable future etc.

Comment: @amritanshu Your response is good, I'll give you that, but I'd like to point out that if he was able to explain wanting something like "how to use Asynch channel with Completable future etc." then he'd have resorted to google for the answer, if he didn't already know it himself anyway. :P +1 though.

Comment: The API is just like document retrieval/creation gateway. sort of Datawarehouse. some clients will create the documents and other clients will retrieve the document stored.   It will be stored as the same file pdf/jpg on to the Linux machine. For reference the above code that I have used  took around 75ms to write  a 25Mb pdf file.

Comment: @Wayne I know, I couldn't think of a better example in the current context. I predate the SO era, where mailing lists would be the way to go and you can ask questions at your own peril. These are gentler times, where everyone is trying to help everyone.

Comment: @amritanshu yeah, that's true, which is both good and bad imho. Good job on the answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using memory mapped files. We have used these for fast, shared read/write access to data set up to 40x main memory size.

You can use plan MappedByteBuffer from RandomAccessFile, or use a library like mine.

A low level file memory access

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes/blob/master/src/test/java/net/openhft/chronicle/bytes/MappedMemoryTest.java

An append only queue/journal built on memory mapped files.
https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue

A key/value store built on memory mapped files.
https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map

> For reference the above code that I have used took around 75ms to write a 25Mb pdf file.

I assume you meant 25 MB (Megabytes) not Mb (Megabits) and that translates to 333 MB/s which is reasonable for a single desktop SSD. i.e. most likely the problem is you are working at the limit of what your disk sub-system can do.

BTW You can buy an NVMe drive which can do around to 2 GB/s for less than $1000.

Comment: mostly curious (and with a lot of time to spare) memory mapped files are great if you have few really big files that are accessed again and again. If its a file server does it really give any extra advantage? It makes cleanup tricky as well. Why not just cache the buffers around for top K access instead?

Comment: @amritanshu if the OP is creating and closing lots of files, you are right that memory mapped won't help and could make things more complicated. I think it is more likely that the access pattern is working close to the limit if the underlying disk sub system in which case you need faster disks.

Comment: This is not practical unless you know the exact output size of each image in advance.

Comment: @EJP The two solutions I mentioned, Queue and Map, you don't need to know the exact size in advance and can handle anything between a few bytes and 1 GB efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do to your existing code is to use a `BufferedOutputStream`, thus:

```
OutputStream imageOutFile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("path/filename"));
```

This will make a substantial difference.

There is exactly zero reason to believe that a non-blocking API would be faster, even if it existed for file I/O in Java, which it doesn't.

If you know the output size exactly in advance, you could use a `MappedByteBuffer`, but you don't, so you can't.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I have a measly reputation to afford that, but there is a difference between performance and faster. Asynchronous code is more performant than blocking code and AsynchronousFileChannel does use OS' native interface so there is an asynch file IO  library that does exist.

Comment: @amritanshu Please explain the difference between performance and faster, and let me explain to you that non-blocking and asynchronous I/O are two different things, not two names for the same thing. Otherwise you wouldn't have both `SocketChannel` and `AsynchronousSocketChannel`, for example. There is no non-blocking `FileChannel` variant in Java.

Comment: AsynchronousFileChannel is there pls check it out. Performance could be a measure of latency/responsiveness or it could be just throughput MBps. Asynchronous IO results in better responsiveness without impacting the throughput adversely. Although I am sure there might not be non-blocking File library, it's utility is moot.

Comment: @amritanshu I suspect the problem is the implicit flush of the file on the close() For a 21 MB file how you write that won't matter provided its in reasonable block sizes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey that is a nice observation, I won't call myself a 'native' java developer so I missed the implicit flush, but for a stream it should still result in a buffered write to the file, rather than the file buffer flush to disk?

Comment: @PeterLawrey There is no inmplicit `flush()` when closing a `FileOutputStream`. The data is unbuffered and has already been written, at least to the operating system. In any case `FileOutputStream.flush()` does nothing. It is `FilterOutputStream` where the implicit flush on close occurs.

Comment: @amritanshu `AsynchronousFileChannel` does indeed exist, and I haven't stated otherwise, but it doesn't do non-blocking I/O, so it is therefore irrelevant. Unless you think non-blocking == asynchronous, which it isn't, as I have also already stated: otherwise, for example, `SocketChannel.configureBlocking()` and `AsynchronousSocketChannel` wouldn't both exist. And note that `FileChannel.configureBlocking()` does *not* exist. I haven't said anything about throughput in MB/s either. All I said was 'faster', and both your definitions of performance equal speed.

Comment: @EJP The JVM doesn't specify that a flush/sync to disk must occur, never the less Linux does tend to sync the data on a closed file handle which can cause performance problems. I have seen large servers lockup for as long as 40 seconds on the close of a large file. (About 50 GB as dirty)

Comment: @EJP yes but your answer talks about non blocking API, for OP and for most others for all practical purpose all async IO is non-blocking while the converse is not true (as you have pointed out a few times). It is not totally wrong to ask for Non-blocking way of doing things when you mean an asynchronous way of doing things. Also, no latency(of response) and throughput(of data) don't mean speed, I don't know what speed means in such an abstract situation. Also, I appreciate your need to be accurate all answers should be! But we should discount the need for accuracy in questions.

Comment: @amritanshu My answer talks about non-blocking I/O, as does the question. We are entitled to assume the OP is using terminology precisely, and to make it more precise when necessary. Non-blocking I/O is not the same as asynchronous I/O, and it fulfils no useful purpose to keep repeating otherwise. Latency and speed are both measured with time. The purpose of SO is to provide correct answers, as I have tried to do here, your irrelevant approximations notwithstanding. I really have no idea what point you are trying to make here. You are just creating confusion where none exists. Please don't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes. There is no question that the OS has to flush the data to the disk. If that's all you meant I am happy.

Comment: @EJP all asynchronous FILE IO is non-blocking I/O, there is no confusion except that you keep on denying it. What is speed in this context I still don't get it, you choose to be accurate or vague/generic in the same sentence. Also, downvoted a perfectly relevant answer it wasn't mine but was adding value. It is ok though I have found very few people who would change their opinion over an internet discussion.